# Getting stackOverFlow error within a run method

Tags: java, multithreading, function, methods, stack-overflow

This is the method that is getting the error

```
public int getMaxTimeBetweenCustomers()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(maxTimeBetweenCustomers);
    }
```

and this is the run method where the above^ method is being called. If I try to initialize the variable outside the method it does not work, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
 private void doSomething() throws InterruptedException
        {
         maxCustomers = myController.getMaxCustomers();
           int myCounter=0;
            String message;
            while(myCounter < maxCustomers)
            {
               Customer customer= this.generateCustomer();
               myServiceQueue = myServiceQueueManager.determineShortestQueue();
               myServiceQueue.insertCustomer(customer);
                 myTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                myController.controllSetImages();


                myCounter++;
                System.out.println("my counter " + myCounter);


                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(this.generateTimeBetweenCustomers());
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    message = e.getMessage();
                    System.err.println(message);
                }

            }
        }
```

The above method doSomething() is called in the run method

Comment: Your code is going in an infinite loop!

Comment: The `getMaxTimeBetweenCustomers` cannot possibly cause the SO exception.

Comment: @SameerSawla: it's more than an infinite loop -- it's recursing.

Comment: stack trace would be useful

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `StackOverflowError` and look at the stack.

Comment: doSomething does not call getMaxTimeBetweenCustomers

Answer (score 2):

You state that the `getMaxTimeBetweenCustomers()` method is causing your program to throw a StackOverflowException, but this is impossible if this method only contains the line of code you've shown. Something else is going on.

Likely that something else is that you've recursion going on. I have to guess, but perhaps `doSomething()` is being called directly or indirectly from within one of the methods it contains, one of the methods listed below:

- `this.generateCustomer();`
- `myController.getMaxCustomers();`
- `myServiceQueueManager.determineShortestQueue();`
- `myServiceQueue.insertCustomer(customer);`
- `myController.controllSetImages();`